# How to manage maintenance

Tags: maintenance

There are lots of great books and resources out there about managing new software developments, but very little that I've seen about managing ongoing maintenance of software systems. I'm not talking about big enhancements, I'm talking about the little 1 or 2 day bug fixes and updates that quickly accumulate once a system goes into production.

Any recommended books or other resources on this subject?

Answer (score 7):

**"[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131177052)" by Michael Feathers is a good place to start.**

He provides a comprehensive overview of how to work within a large codebase. Ostensibly his focus is how to manage refactoring safely, but the principles he provides would work well for maintenance coding as well.

Comment: it's one of my favorite tech books. Good suggestion :)

Comment: @Rein Mine too. Sits right beside Pragmatic Programmer on the bookshelf.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard that [FogBuz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) is a great tool. The biggest coding shop I was in was during my time in the Marine Corps. I wish there was a tool like [FogBuz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) back then (1989 - 1999).

Most of my programming experience outside of the Marine Corps has been web development. We would build widgets and then resell them as add-ons to other customers. Of course bugs would surface and version changes would happen. We simply created version folders in our code library.

In addition to the source files we would maintain the SQL scripts inside these version folders to include utility stored procs for converting data from version x to version y.

It's not the perfect solution, but it worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned Michael Feather's book which I highly recommend; but there is also one useful article. Although a joke article, it does provide tips on what you **absolutely shouldn't do** with your code:

> [How To Write Unmaintainable Code - Roedy Green](http://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html)

In maintenance, it is usually simpler to understand what you **shouldn't** do rather than giving rules on what you **should** do.